# Find mean position of blackpixels using python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, video-processing

I have a binary image and I need to find the mean values of x and y of the black region. These values are calculated for a set of binary images and their mean values of x and y are plotted I don't know how to find this region and calculate their mean values of x and y. Any help is kindly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: use `cv2.moments`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If black pixels are not registered in some data structure, just calculate center of mass for black pixels:

```
sx = 0
sy = 0
black_cnt = 0
for y in y-range
  for x in x-range
     if black(x,y)
          sx = sx + x
          sy = sy + y
          black_cnt++

sx = sx / black_cnt
sy = sy / black_cnt
```

Comment: I am getting `IndexError: index 255 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 200`  this error

Comment: what do you mean by wrong cycle, `im = cv2.imread('v6.tif', 0) 
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(im, 120, 255, 1)
a = len(im)
print thresh
b = a+2
sx = 0
sy = 0
blackc = 0
for x in range(a):
      for y in range(a):
            pixel = im[x,y]
            if pixel == 0:
                  sx = sx+x
                  sy = sy+y
                  blackc +=1                  
print blackc
cv2.waitKey()` I am doing this

Comment: You are using `for x in range(a)` while x should be in range(width) and y in range(height)

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the mean positions using the **moments of contours**.

In order to find the mean you must calculate the first order moments of the contour.

CODE:

```
#---Read image and obtain threshold---
im = cv2.imread('1.jpg', 1)
img = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 120, 255, 1)

#---Obtain contours---
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = contours
cv2.drawContours(im, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)

#---Compute the center/mean of the contours---
for c in cnts:
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    print cX
    print cY
```

Values `cX` and `cY` have the mean positions of the contours.

Comment: I tired this method and i am getting `contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
ValueError: too many values to unpack` this error

Comment: @the_guy it is a version problem try: `_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`